# Enter the text box value before?

Tags: c#, .net, if-statement, textbox

I want to user to enter textbox value before continue the run next method. After message box shows and click ok. application goes to MyNextMethod. Therefore I cannot enter my valid value to text box.

```
    If (textbox1 =="")
    {
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter valid entery.")
    }
    MyNextMethod();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
return;
```

after

```
MessageBox.Show();
```

function

Answer (score 3):

```
  If (textbox1.Text == string.empty)
  {
      MessageBox.Show("Please enter valid entery.")
  }
  else
  {
      MyNextMethod();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is your requirement or goal:
You want user to enter textbox value before continue the run next method. It is OK with your old code.
If (textbox1 =="")
    {
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter valid entery.")
    }
But you call MyNextMethod() method, it means whether user enter the value or not you allow to go MyNextMethod().

Conclusion, you can do as you like:

**1.** you can append return; after MessageBox.Show(); as first Answer

**2.** you can also call MyNextMethod() with else. as 2nd Answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use `textbox onChange()` event. If text is changed in `textbox`, check if entered value is a number and calculate total value according to the other value. try this code

```
If (textbox1.Text =="" || textbox1.Text.Length==0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter valid entery.");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
else
{
     MyNextMethod();
}
```

You can also use `textbox1_LostFocus()` so when `Focus` lost you can call your `NextMethod`

```
private void textBox1_LostFocus(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   MyNextMethod();
}
```

Comment: comparing textbox1 with string is not valid!

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this if textbox is empty

```
if(textbox1.text=="")
{
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "validation", "<script language='javascript'>alert('Please enter text')</script>");
}
else
{
     // your next method
}
```